# UIAlertView asking to access current location wrong orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uialertview

My app currently asks the user for access to their current location, so when the app launches it shows the UIAlertView asking for it. The issue is that my app is set only for portrait mode, but the UIAlertView is displayed in landscape. I'd have to rotate the phone to have it oriented correctly. What am I missing here?

Comment: "that my app is set only for portrait mode" ...can you show the code you are using to set it to portrait only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this post:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/more-on-uialertview-and-landscape.html

Basically you may need to try something like this before the alert.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

UPDATE: Here is a SO with an alternate solution post.

[Rotating a UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859438/rotating-a-uialertview)