# Alertview created by UIImagePicker showing sideways

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uialertview

I have an `alertview` auto generated by `UIImagePickerController` which is used for taking videos. After recording the video for the max duration, the pop-up message is shown sideways.

I know for different os, we can do 
`if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))` to use UIAlertController or UIAlertView to prevent showing sideways.

However, I'm not the one who initializes this view, `UIImagePickerController` is.

How could I achieve the same?

The one answer I found on StackOverflow that might be useful is this:
[How to respond to UIImagePickerController Generated UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541790/how-to-respond-to-uiimagepickercontroller-generated-uialertview)

I don't think this gonna help with my problem here tho.

Comment: Have you tried the answer you've found out?

Comment: Hi aribeiro, I haven't. I will try it later, kinda caught up with other things. Will be really appreciate if anyone has dealt with this problem. thanks. i'm thinking maybe doing something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859438/rotating-a-uialertview      in the notification. and also the dark background only covers about 3/4 in width of the screen and the alertview is in the center of this background.

Comment: Are you using swift or objective-c? You tagged both.

Comment: Hi Troy T, i'm using objecitve c here, either language is fine with me.

Comment: I added the notification, but no luck rotating the uiwindow as I desired.